Cannot see template repo from template - Azure DevOps
I have a template in devops repo in projectB, in the same repo I also have some scripts and default configuration files. From my code repo in projectA I am able to reference the template but the devops repo is not checked out.
code-repo-pipeline.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: git
      name: ProjectB/devops
      ref: refs/tags/latest

stages:
  - stage: Pipeline
    jobs:
      - job: Checkout
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - checkout: devops
          - script: |
              tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)  # Here I see both repos

      - template: templates/pipeline.yaml@devops

devops-template.yml
jobs:
  - job: Check
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - script: |
          tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)  # Here I only see the code repo

How should I configure it? Thanks
I tried to checkout the current (devops) repo from the template, but in this case the devops repo overrides the code repo.

Did my answer help?

Considering a repository like this:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops # <----------- repository alias
      type: git
      name: ProjectB/devops
      ref: refs/tags/latest

When using shared YAML templates you just need to reference a specific template using special syntax @<repository-alias> - example:
variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/prod-variables@devops

But in the case of other files such as scripts or configuration files you mentioned, you need to checkout the code of the correspondent repository using the checkout task:
steps:
  # ...
  - checkout: devops
  # ...

Also, keep in mind that each job runs on its own process/machine/container. You need to change your template to include the checkout task if you plan to use the scripts or other files:
# devops-template.yaml

parameters:
  - name: repository
    displayName: Repository containing scripts and other files
    type: string
    default: devops # repository alias set in the 'repository' property

jobs:
  - job: Check
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: ${{ parameters.repository }}
      - script: |
          tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)

Checkout folder for the devops repository is $(Pipeline.Workspace)/devops, given that you'll be checking out multiple repositories in your pipeline.
